# Wildcat in AddRazorPagesOptions Conventions.AddPageRoute

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have this code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddMvc()
        .AddRazorPagesOptions(options => {
            options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Index", "Index.html");
            options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/rt", "rt.html");
        });
}
```

Is it possible instead of writing each page, have one wildcat route like this?

```
options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/*", "/{*.html}");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in way to add such wildcard route. However you could achieve it with simple page route convention (implementation of `IPageRouteModelConvention`). Here is a working sample:

```
public class HtmlExtensionPageRouteModelConvention : IPageRouteModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(PageRouteModel model)
    {
        var selectorCount = model.Selectors.Count;
        for (var i = 0; i < selectorCount; ++i)
        {
            var attributeRouteModel = model.Selectors[i].AttributeRouteModel;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(attributeRouteModel.Template))
            {
                continue;
            }

            attributeRouteModel.SuppressLinkGeneration = true;
            model.Selectors.Add(new SelectorModel
            {
                AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel
                {
                    Template = $"{attributeRouteModel.Template}.html",
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Configuration:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddMvc()
        .AddRazorPagesOptions(options => {
            options.Conventions.Add(new HtmlExtensionPageRouteModelConvention());
        });
}
```

[**Sample Project on GitHub**](https://github.com/CodeFuller/stackoverflow/tree/Q49709615-AddPageRoute-All-Pages)